# What is the difference between `new` and `build` in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I do not understand this line of a code:

```
@club = current_user.clubs.build(club_params)
```

I know that the same code can be created with `new` method, and then we can save the instance variable, but what does `build` do in this case?

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Relation#build` did work slightly differently in early versions of Rails but now `build` is just an alias of `new`.

Answer (score 7):

new is for a new instance of a specific model:

```
foo = Foo.new
```

build is for creating a new instance within an AR association:

```
bar = foo.build_bar  # (has_one or belongs_to)
```

or

```
bar = foo.bars.build # (has\_many, habtm or has_many :through)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

**Update**

build and new are aliases as defined in [ActiveRecord::Relation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/959fb8ea651fa6638aaa7caced20d921ca2ea5c1/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L84):

So if class Foo has_many Bars, the following have identical effects:

- `foo.bars.new` <=> `foo.bars.build`
- `Bar.where(:foo_id=>foo.id).new` <=> `Bar.where(:foo_id=>foo.id).build`

And if `!foo.new_record?`

- `foo.bars.new` <=> `Bar.where(:foo_id=>foo.id).new`

Answer (score 1):

**New and build are same as per the documentation** https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb

Answer (score -1):

build and new both are almost same but have difference of that build is used when you are using belongs_to in association

In this patient belongs_to user so we used build

```
belongs_to :user
@patient = current_user.patients.build(patient_params) 
@patient.save
```